# Touchpad not working at all on Toshiba Satellite with 18.04

Tags: touchpad, 18.04, toshiba-satellite

After a fresh install of 18.04, the touchpad does not work at all on my Toshiba Satellite S55-A5295. Wireless Logitech mouse works perfectly. After an hour of Googling, I'm not able to find a solution.  Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue on my Satellite L50. No solution for it yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the trackpad is disabled on startup.

To enable, press the trackpad enable/disable button on the keyboard (In my case: <kbd>Function</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution somewhere else online:

Boot into BIOS and press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>. There will be no indication that anything has changed; but, if you touch the touchpad, you'll see your mouse arrow. Use the same key combination to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem except perhaps for the fact that my touchpad worked in windows 10. Other solutions, like modifying grub or disabling and enabling the touchpad did not work for me. I could see it listed in devices menu but my cursor was stuck.
**This is how I got mine working again;**

1. I booted into windows 10
2. Located and ran the synaptics installer that came with the laptop
3. Shutdown
4. Booted into Ubuntu
5. touchpad started working